# Why am I getting a client error in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, client, typeerror

I am making a !stats command in my discord.js bot using this [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/).
As I am using the basic command handler, here is my stats.js code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: 'React to a message',
    execute(message, client) {
        message.channel.send(`Server count: ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
    },
};
```

And then I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
    at Object.execute (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\commands\Utility\stats.js:5:55)
    at Object.execute (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\events\message.js:69:12)
    at Client.<anonymous> (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\bot.js:30:61)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)   
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)  
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) 
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\The Owner\Naffy Dharni\Discord\Bots\Toxado Manager\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is before the `cache` property is `undefined`.

So in your case that's client.guilds. Given that this can't be undefined for a proper djs client object you are probably not passing your values in the proper order when calling that file. That is, `client` is probably not an actual djs client class/object.

Answer (score -1):

What you discord.js version use?
Caches added on 12version.
Use `npm i discord.js@12` or just remove called on field `cache`.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: 'React to a message',
    execute(message, client) {
        message.channel.send(`Server count: ${client.guilds.size}`);
    },
};
```